# Arduino Uno: Driving a small LED strip with 2N3904 NPN

Tags: led, transistor

I'd like to know why I cannot dim the small LED strip with my design. I can only turn them on and off. This is a problem for me as I wanted to have a fade effect. Here is my circuit:

[image: Circuit using fritzing]

The voltage from the power jack is 5 volts. My NPN transistor is a 2N3904 (from left to right: emitter, base, collector).
For the Arduino I am only using the fade exemple sketch:

```
int led = A2; // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int brightness = 0; // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 5; // how many points to fade the LED by

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
 }

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // set the brightness of pin 9:
  analogWrite(led, brightness);

  // change the brightness for next time through the loop:
  brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

  // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
  if (brightness <= 0 || brightness >= 255) {
     fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
  }
  // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
  delay(30);
}
```

By the way, this is my first post so please tell me if something is wrong with it! Thank you for your help!

Have a nice day.

Comment: *The voltage from the power jack is 5 volts* - what do you mean by that? Are you feeding 5V into that thing at the top of the picture (into Vin?). I'm a little surprised the LEDs light up at all, since the forward voltage for a red LED is around 2V, and with 5 in series, they will be getting 1V each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `analogWrite` works only on `PWM` pins (in your scheme it's marked by ~). On the other pins it's possible to set only `LOW`/`HIGH` (values under `128` are translated to the `LOW`)

Not to mention weirdly used `NPN` with LEDs as negative feedback. But that's why it doesn't burned out yet. The usual way is connect the Emmiter to the ground and base is driven over current limiting resistor (about 1k).
This is how we usualy use `PNP` transistor (again with 1k resistor and emitter to the `Vcc`, not the collector). But `PNP` won't work with `5V` logic and higher `Vin` than `5V` as there will be current flow from `0V` or `5V` to the `Vin`.

Comment: The unusual NPN connection you show is called an emitter follower circuit.  The emitter will follow the base voltage -.7V or -1.4v for a darlington. I assume you are powering it by the USB.

Comment: @gil He has 5 LEDs in series (roughly about 9V @ 10mA) and emmiter follower with 0 or 5V in the base...